# Multiple Font Sizes for h1 element via CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to display a company name so that the "main" part of the name appears on one line and is huge and the secondary part of the name is centered below it and smaller.  Since it's not a slogan or "subtitle", I feel like it should all be in the same `h1` element and, ideally, be transformed through pure CSS (meaning no spans or `em`s if it can be avoided.

Example:

```
<h1>Big Bill's Custom Auto Parts</h1>
```

should appear as:

## Big Bill's

#### Custom Auto Parts

Is there a pure CSS way of doing this (even a pseudo-class not fully supported yet)?

Comment: And the reason for wanting to do that is? ...

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester - If I add a span, it would be for presentation only. If I use multiple headers, it would break the document outline. Having it be one h1 is better for SEO, and just "correct". Avoiding a presentation only span is always something to strive for, I think. Hence me asking my peers if they knew of a way rather than taking the obvious shortcut.

Comment: That would be the most extreme form of SEO I've ever seen then. If you just put <title>Big Bill's custom auto parts</title> in your <head> tag, you'll be fine. Besides, for what else would you use a html element than for presentation??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it permissible to include a new line in the heading itself? If so you can use the first-line selector like this:

HTML

```
<h1>Foo bar                                                                                            
baz</h1>
```

CSS

```
h1 {
  font-size:1em;
  white-space:pre;
}
h1:first-line {
  font-size:3em;
}
```

Comment: That's actually pretty clever.  I can't count on the new line being preserved, unfortunately. +1 for a good idea though.

Comment: @Anthony I'm all out of ideas. Is Javascript out of the question?

Comment: I was going to go Javascript as a fallback for older browsers. But since there is no new/experimental way of doing it, I think the `span` or `em` is the way to go, since the "main" part of the header has some contextual significance that separates it from the rest of the header (and I imagine most use-cases this would be true). But it would be cool to have the ability to make the first three words of a  text node green (or bold, or whatever) just as a style choice.

Comment: If you can't be sure the literal newline is going to be preserved, another option is to use an entity, e.g.: `<h1>Foo&#13;&#10;Bar</h1>`.

Answer (score 6):

Not possible, it seems to make more sense that you have two different headers and can be styled accordingly.

How would you possibly specify where changes happen without adding a `<span>` within the `<h1>`?

Comment: I agree, there is too much inferred logic here for css to handle this with one definition.

Comment: With nth pseudo-selectors, along with `::first-letter`, etc, I was hoping for something like `::nth-letters` or `::nth-words`.  Hopeful, maybe, but not crazy, I don't think. Especially since it would be more "right" to do it that way since the `span` would be presentational only.

Comment: @Anthony I think you're being too much of a purist. As far as the document structure is concerned, there is nothing wrong with considering that title as two separate elements. If you really care about the single tag (maybe for search bots), there is no problem with adding a span to make part of the title look different

Comment: @JuanMendes - I try to be as pure as possible.  If it can be done via CSS, I want to go that route, if it can't be done, I'll take the span. But as long as I'm not up against a deadline, I'll always at least check the specs and ask around before assuming the purest approach is not possible.

Comment: @Anthony I really think you're taking HTML way too literally. You're going to keep bumping into limitations and the only real reason that `span` is there is to apply different styling to something inline. By looking into hacks you damage your own purity anyway. NO web site out there follows the HTML specs literally and it can't even be done cause no browser adheres to them either.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest solution to this without using extra headers is the use of a span element:

```
<h1><span>Big Bill's</span> Custom Auto Parts</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1.span {
  /* styling rules */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with breaking the line with a `<br/>`, then you might accomplish this using the [`::first-line` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3a%3afirst-line).

Comment: I'd rather avoid the break, unless it was inserted with CSS, but that would imply I could insert at a specific point without needing a wrapper. But the `::first-line` would be better than what I originally was messing with, which was `h2`s wrapped in an `h1`.

Comment: You could also break the line with a literal newline and use `white-space: pre` to have it displayed properly.

Answer (score 1):

You said you want to do it in pure CSS way, separating content and presentation. No addtional `spans`, no `br`. I understand it, but if you think about your problem, you want to create **presentation rule based on content**. Is that making sense? Isn't that mixing content with presentation you want to avoid?

Comment: Not if it's done in the presentation layer (ie stylesheet).  No more so than `::first-letter` or `::first-line`.  An argument can be made, of course, that the first part goes on top because it has some contextual significance, so it's not totally un-semantic to wrap it in its own element. But having been presented with the scenario, I was curious to see if anyone knew of a way to achieve the same effect with only CSS.

Answer (score -1):

I tried other stuff in this thread, but this finally worked.

```
<h3>Tutorials <span style="font-size:14px;">(2 of them)</span></h3>
```